# What is the JDK version that was used to compile the Tuckey UrlRewriteFilter JAR?

Tags: tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

What is the JDK version that was used to compile the Tuckey UrlRewriteFilter JAR ?

Tuckey UrlRewriteFilter Home page :

http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/

JAR :

http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/tuckey/urlrewritefilter/4.0.3/urlrewritefilter-4.0.3.jar

Answer (score 0):

It was built with this : Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_21

By the way, generally you can either unzip the jar and see the manifest file or you can use javap command on any class in that jar which tells the compiler version ( for future references)